# Fix for Visual Studio 2005 not showing filename or line on errors in web pages when compiling?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005

A project I'm on requires Visual Studio 2005.  One annoyance is that when a website project in the solution, any compile errors from .aspx or .ascx files show up like:

```
(0,0): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
(0,0): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
(0,0): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
(0,0): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
```

How can I track these down?  Is there an option I'm missing that gives me filename and line numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Try double clicking them. Also check to make sure all the columns are displayed in the error window.

Comment: @spoulson Sometimes if you hit rebuild you'll be able to get to them. They'll typically be displayed above. Do you have a "warnings" tab? in your error list? I've seen some that can't be clicked but never knew why. Are you using code in-line model?

Comment: Rebuild gives me the same result.  The quoted block in the question comes from the Output window.  The Error window displays basically the same thing--no filename, line number, nor project name.  Doubleclicking that also does nothing.